# $f$ is differentiable everywhere, does that imply $f'$ is bounded in small nieghborhoods

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

The motivation of this question is when I am looking at Taylor's Remainder theorem, suppose $f$ is $n+1$ differentiable, then the remainder can be written as 
$$R_{n+1}(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{n!} x^{n+1} \quad \text{ where } c\in [0,x],$$
but I don't see  $R_{n+1}(x) \in O(x^{n+1})$ if we have no control of $f^{(n+1)}(c)$ for $c\in [0,x]$.

I know since $f'$ is a pointwise limit of continuous functions, thus it is continuous on a dense set, would this help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A counterexample to the question in the title is yielded by the function defined by $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ if $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$. This is differentiable everywhere with $f'(0)=0$ (use the definition of the derivative). But if $m\in\mathbb{N}$, then $f'(m^{-1})=-2m\cos(m^2)+2\sin(m^2)/m$ and as $m\to\infty$, $\sin(m^2)/m\to 0$ and $\left|2m\cos(m^2)\right|$ oscillates wildly between $0$ and $2m$. So on any nbhd of $0$, the derivative is not bounded.

Comment: Ah yes, I overlooked this classic example. Then how would we apply the Taylor Remainder theorem in this case. $R_1(x) = f'(c) x $ and how would we show $R_1(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Cute modification of $x\sin(1/x)$ :-) I suppose we would write $f(x)=f(0)+R_1(x)$ and thus $R_1(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ and conclude that $R_1(x)$ is continuous. More to the point, using the MVT on the RHS yields you $f'(c_x)x$ and because equality is unambiguous, you can conclude that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(c_x)x=\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)-f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}R_1(x)=0$ since $f$ is continuous.